# How Entity Framework commands by SQL commands?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-order-by

How can I do this in a C# code with SQL Server commands, not Entity Framework?

I just want to understand `orderby` topic in SQL Server that I learned about in Entity Framework but not in SQL Server. Thanks!

```
using (KariyerDBEntities db = new DBEntities())
{
    IEnumerable<Product> ProductList = db.Products.ToList();

    var result = ProductList.OrderBy(e => e.Stock)
                            .ThenByDescending(e => e.Name)
                            .ThenByDescending(e => e.Price)
                            .ThenByDescending(e => e.CreateDate);

    foreach (var p in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Id + "  " + p.Name + "  " + p.Price + "  " + p.Stock + "  " + p.CreateDate + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Dapper is a nice micro-ORM, very little overhead, doesn't do change tracking, but it will map your table into objects

Answer (score 1):

Turn on [EF logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/) and you can see the SQL generated.  This

```
var result = ProductList.OrderBy(e => e.Stock).ThenByDescending(e => e.Name).ThenByDescending(e => e.Price).ThenByDescending(e => e.CreateDate);
```

should be something like

```
select * from product
order by Stock asc, Name desc, Price desc, CreateDate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add Columns dynamically, instead of hardcode the name of the columns, you should use metadata to build the `String` you want to print.

You can use the `SqlDataReader.GetColumnSchema` method to get a collection of `DbColumn`.

Then you could build your code based on the `DbColumn.ColumnName` property.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you to look for DataTable.

It can call rows or columns.

Like this.

DataTable dt;
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())

dt.Rows[0]
dt.Rows[1]